# Why doesn't my $q.defer().resolve work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, q

As the demo shows,when I define my promise in service and return it back(promise1 in the demo),it doesn't resolve at all.

But when I define the promise(promise2 in the demo) in controller,it works good.Why?

[this is my demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/leejun/pen/xVXvmz?editors=1010)

```
serv.getDefer = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    return {
      defer: defer,
      promise: defer.promise
    }
}

var defer1 = serv.getDefer().defer;
var promise1 = serv.getDefer().promise;
promise1.then(function() {
    alert('promise1 should work,but doesnt')
})
defer1.resolve();

var defer2 = serv.getDefer().defer;
var promise2 = defer2.promise;
promise2.then(function() {
    alert('promise2 works good')
})
defer2.resolve();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into closures, the second time you call the function getDefer(), it makes a new variable, and returns it.

However, this might work (not tested though)

```
var deferred = serv.getDefer();
deferred.promise.then(function() {
    alert('promise1 should work,but doesnt')
});
deferred.defer.resolve();
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `serv.getDefer()` it returns a new deffered object, in your promise 1 you call `serv.getDefer()` both to create `defer1` and `promise1`. The 2 variables now aren't the same promise, so when you resolve `defer1`, the promise of `promise1` is still unresolved.

in your second example `promise2` is the promise of `defer2`, so when you resolve `defer2` the promise will be resolved.

to fix this you have to do the following:

```
var deferred = serv.getDefer(),
    defer1 = deferred.defer
    promise1 = deferred.promise;

promise1.then(function() {
  alert('promise1 should work,but doesnt')
});

defer1.resolve();
```

Answer (score 1):

promise1 is not generated by defer1. Instead, you are creating a new deferred object by calling getDefer() again.

promise2 works because it is generated by defer2.promise()

I think the line should be

```
var promise1 = defer1.promise;
```